# pyspark seaching keywords with regex and then join with other dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes

dataframe A

```
name       groceries 
Mike       apple, orange, banana, noodle, red wine
Kate       white wine, green beans, extra pineapple hawaiian pizza
Leah       red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans
Ben        water, spaghetti
```

dataframe B

```
id       item
0001     red wine
0002     green beans
```

I'm going through B row by row, and using regex to search if item exists in groceries in dataframe A

```
df = None
for keyword in B.select('item').rdd.flatMap(lambda x : x).collect():
    if keyword == None:
        continue
    pattern = '(?i)^'
    start = '(?=.*\\b'
    end = '\\b)'
    for word in re.split('\\s+', keyword):
        pattern = pattern + start + word + end
    pattern = pattern + '.*$'
    
    if df == None:
        df = A.filter(A['groceries'].rlike(pattern)).withColumn('item', F.lit(keyword))
    else:
        df = df.unionAll(A.filter(A['groceries'].rlike(pattern)).withColumn('item', F.lit(keyword)))
```

My desired output is rows in A that contains item from B, but also with the item keyword inserted as a new column

```
name       groceries                                                     item
Mike       apple, orange, banana, noodle, red wine                       red wine
Leah       red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans                    red wine
Kate       white wine, green beans, extra pineapple hawaiian pizza       green beans
Leah       red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans                    green beans
```

The actual output is not what I want, I dont understand what is incorrect with this approach.

I was also wondering if there is a way that I can use rlike to directly join A and B so that rows will join only if item in A exist in groceries in B. Thanks!

More complicated dataset

```
test1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mike","apple, oranges, red wine"),("Kate","Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine"), ("Leah", "red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans"),("Ben","Water,Spaghetti, the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["name","groceries"])
test2 = spark.createDataFrame([("001","red wine"),("002","green beans waterrr"), ("003", "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["id","item"])
#%%
test_join =test1.join(test2,F.expr("""groceries rlike item"""),how='inner').show(truncate = False)
```

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---+-------------------+
|name|groceries                                          |id |item               |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---+-------------------+
|Mike|apple, oranges, red wine                           |001|red wine           |
|Kate|Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine|001|red wine           |
|Kate|Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine|002|green beans waterrr|
|Leah|red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans         |001|red wine           |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+---+-------------------+
```

Even though there is an exact keyword match for "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)", it still wont match in the result

```
test1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mike","apple, oranges, red wine"),("Kate","Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine"), ("Leah", "red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans"),("Ben","Water,Spaghetti, the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["name","groceries"])
test2 = spark.createDataFrame([("001","red apple"),("002","green beans waterrr"), ("003", "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["id","item"])
```

--------------- if I do a rlike with regex to look for "red apple" like below ---------------

```
test1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mike","apple, oranges, red wine"),("Kate","Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine"), ("Leah", "red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans"),("Ben","Water,Spaghetti, the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["name","groceries"])
test2 = spark.createDataFrame([("001","red apple"),("002","green beans waterrr"), ("003", "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["id","item"])

test_join = test1.filter(test1['groceries'].rlike('(?i)^(?=.*\\bred\\b)(?=.*\\bapple\\b).*$'))
```

```
+----+------------------------+
|name|groceries               |
+----+------------------------+
|Mike|apple, oranges, red wine|
+----+------------------------+
```

it will give me what I want since I just want to confirm all the words in item are present in groceries even if they are out of order. whereas, doing the below wont give me the above matching

```
test_join =test1.join(test2,F.expr("""groceries rlike item"""),how='inner').show(truncate = False)
test_join =test1.join(test2,F.col('groceries').contains(F.col('item')),how='inner')
```

Solution:

```
def my_udf(keyword):
    if keyword == None:
        return ''
    pattern = '(?i)^'
    start = '(?=.*\\b'
    end = '\\b)'
    for word in re.split('\\s+', keyword):
        pattern = pattern + start + word + end
    pattern = pattern + '.*$'
    return pattern

regex_udf = udf(my_udf, T.StringType())
B = B.withColumn('regex', regex_udf(B['item']))

regex_join = A.join(B, F.expr("""groceries rlike regex"""), how = 'inner')
```

It managed to do what I wanted but still ran pretty slow. It is maybe because of join and the use of udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rlike joins are possible using F.expr(). In your case you need to use it with an inner join. try this,

```
    #%%
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test1 =sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Mike","apple,greenbeans,redwine,the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)" ),("kate","Whitewine,greenbeans,pineapple"),("Ben","Water,Spaghetti")],schema=["name","groceries"])
test2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("001","redwine"),("002","greenbeans"),("003","cd")],schema=["id","item"])
#%%
test_join =test1.join(test2,F.expr("""groceries rlike item"""),how='inner')
```

result:

```
 test_join.show(truncate=False)
   +----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----------+
|name|groceries                                                                                        |id |item      |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----------+
|Mike|apple,greenbeans,redwine,the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)|001|redwine   |
|Mike|apple,greenbeans,redwine,the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)|002|greenbeans|
|Mike|apple,greenbeans,redwine,the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)|003|cd        |
|kate|Whitewine,greenbeans,pineapple                                                                   |002|greenbeans|
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----------+
```

For your complex dataset, contains() function must work

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test1 = spark.createDataFrame([("Mike","apple, oranges, red wine,green beans"),("Kate","Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine"), ("Leah", "red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans"),("Ben","Water,Spaghetti, the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["name","groceries"])
test2 = spark.createDataFrame([("001","red wine"),("002","green beans waterrr"), ("003", "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)")],schema=["id","item"])
#%%
test_join =test1.join(test2,F.col('groceries').contains(F.col('item')),how='inner')
```

Results:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|groceries                                                                                |id |item                                                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Mike|apple, oranges, red wine,green beans                                                     |001|red wine                                                                |
|Kate|Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine                                      |001|red wine                                                                |
|Kate|Whitewine, green beans waterrr, pineapple, red wine                                      |002|green beans waterrr                                                     |
|Leah|red wine, juice, rice, grapes, green beans                                               |001|red wine                                                                |
|Ben |Water,Spaghetti, the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)|003|the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: the answer you gave run svery slowly, even though I am using an aws emr cluster with 20 nodes. Also, it seems not working when the keywords in groceries become complicated.

For example, graceries have keywords "the little prince 70th anniversary gift set (book/cd/downloadable audio)"

Even if the exact keywords exist in item, it will not match

Comment: Joins are a costly operation in pyspark. So it will be slow depending on your data size. Consider broadcasting the table 2 if it is small. Regarding the match - we cannot assume how your full data will look like, also the question specifically mentions rlike join. If you need something else, please research more or improve your question.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. the rlike join is  more like a second question from me. the original question as shown in the code snippet meant that I basically took "item" out and form them into regex, and then use .filter to get rows from the table with groceries that match with the regex, and concat all the result together. However it is not doing what I want

Comment: Can you update your question to show the complex case where my answer will not work?

Comment: becuase, the special characers like (book/cd) works for me. check out the updated answer

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have updated the more complicated dataset

Comment: As I understand, contains() is doing exact match. I want to to match even if the words in item are out of order. For example, groceries "water bottle, red wine", and item "red water". these two will still match because all the keywords in item is present in groceries

Comment: Is this of any use to you - https://towardsdatascience.com/spark-join-using-regex-40a8589c0354

Comment: @lookingglass - thanks for accepting. were you able to manage your final requirement. If so , can you share how?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to use the ("groceries rlike item") with some modifications. I changed the item column to regex, and then the rlike was able to match them even if the keywords were out of order. it still runs pretty slow, but at least the code it's clean. I'm still searching for better solutions online

Comment: how did you change the item column to regex? or can you post your code as a part of the question, like finally i manged with this : <your code> ? it will be helpful to others

Comment: updated. maybe you have some ideas of speeding this up!